# Не работает Телеграм-бот на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, telebot, бот

Не работает Telegram-Бот на Python, возможно где-то ошибка в коде. Бот должен парсить данные с сайта [https://sinoptik.ua/погода-шийковка](https://sinoptik.ua/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) и присылать температуру воздуха пользователю

```
import config
import telebot
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get('http://sinoptik.ua/погода-шийковка')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
bot = 'Здесь мой токен'

for el in html.select('#content'):
    t_min = el.select('.temperature .min')[0].text
    t_max = el.select('.temperature .max')[0].text
    text = el.select('.wDescription .description')[0].text

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, погода на сегодня:\n" +
        t_min + ', ' + t_max + '\n' + text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что значит _"не работает"_? Возникает конкретная ошибка, или он неправильно выполняет поставленную задачу (какую, кстати)? Вы можете дополнить вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Здравствуйте, при запуске бота возникает ошибка `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Артем\Python\weatherbot\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'message_handler'` По поводу задачи бот должен парсить данные с сайта и присылать температуру пользователю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Готовый код:***

```
import config
import telebot
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get('http://sinoptik.ua/погода-шийковка')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
bot = telebot.TeleBot('Здесь вводите Ваш токен')

for el in html.select('#content'):
    t_min = el.select('.temperature .min')[0].text
    t_max = el.select('.temperature .max')[0].text
    text = el.select('.wDescription .description')[0].text

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, погода на сегодня:\n" +
        t_min + ', ' + t_max + '\n' + text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не инициализируете класс бота.

***Пример:***

```py
from telebot import TeleBot


bot = TeleBot('Здесь мой токен')
```